# Stacked Bar Chart with Labels

Tags: google-sheets, google-visualization

I would like to create a stacked chart based on the data in A13:D17.
It currently looks like this:
[image]

It should look like this:
[image]

I can remove the data values, but what I am really looking for is the ability to show the data labels on both sides.

Comment: please clarify _show the data labels on both sides_. do you mean you would like the right side to look like the left side in the second picture? where the labels are part of the axis, not the bar?

Comment: Labels could be inside or outside the chart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if this does what you want. It requires changing your data format.
It is creating notes to the right of the values.

[image]

Comment: If you want the chart to look exactly like your example. Copy column C of my data to Column A and enter a space in each cell of Column C.

Comment: Worked perfectly. After formating the information like you have it shown above, I clicked on each bar and added "Data Label" > "Custom". This allowed the proper label to be displayed.