# Showing a small numbered values along side with big numbered values in Google Sheets chart

Tags: google-sheets

I have some major values in a google sheet chart with numbers between 100:1000, I want to show other values which are between 1:30. 
I wanted to combine them in a combo chart but the problem is with the big values that when its combined to form a combo chart the bars are showing according to its numbers which is between 100:1000 while the line of the small values doesn't appear at all as its below the axis of the big value numbers.
How can I show a significant in the small valued numbers which are represented as a line alongside the big valued numbers?

[image: Example chart]

All tutorials are for Excel, not Google Sheets

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stacked Bar Chart with Labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37994728/stacked-bar-chart-with-labels)

Comment: @player0 here is it, thank you: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1x8rY8rpm_c1ZLAcxcPZdOHk23nnxBqIjMD-dtPDl1fQ/edit#gid=0

Comment: @MartinZeitler the question you posted is about percentage values which is much easier than my problem xD

Comment: when charting, there isn't much difference in between relative and absolute values... a stacked chart in every case should look better than bars and a line, which have zero visual relation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would do this by setting a different scale & axis for the large values.

Right-click the chart > Series > [The column that is really bi]

There is a "Axis" drop-down, switch it from "left" to "right"

You can also get there in the chart editor.

Comment: It worked but now i have a straight trend showing up, how can i remove it. here: https://ibb.co/HhzcLVw